# Custom theme reuse Lumas start page

Tags: magento2, theme, luma-theme

I create a custom theme and I want to reuse lumas start page. My theme is having as parent Luma. I created the widget and Block and injected to start page but seems to not picking up the stylesheet. How do I get it work?

Comment: Can you share your code please? This could either be a code issue or you just need to deploy your changes. I suggest reading about [Magento 2's compilation modes](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html)

Comment: If you navigate to magento2/bin and run php magento setup:static-content:deploy this will generate your stylesheets if it hasn't already been done.

Comment: I let my IDE to search by class the lumen sample data and I found that is under `vendor/magento/magento-cms-sample-data/fixtures/style.css` what I was looking for. Would be nice to have the less but now I  will make my own grid